# Laravel - Modifying data for API only for convenience

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, api

Let's assume the following data that is **exactly** being returned like it's stored into database:

```
[
    {
        "user_name": "User 1",
        "photo_file": "user1.jpg"
    },
    {
        "user_name": "User 2",
        "photo_file": "user2.jpg"
    }
    // ...
]
```

I want to use this data in a JavaScript application but I'd like to append a full path of the user's photo, like doing a treatment for the data before returning it to the API. How can I do that using Laravel?

Comment: I use [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume at present you're just converting the results of your query into JSON and returning that. This works, but it does mean the response is tightly coupled to your database structure, which is a bad idea. Ideally you should have a layer of abstraction to handle adding and formatting data, kind of like a view layer in MVC.

There are plenty of solutions for this. I use [Fractal](http://fractal.thephpleague.com) for my Laravel API's. It allows you to easily customise the output of a particular endpoint by specifying a transformer that will render that object for you. That way you can easily choose the data to display and format it how you wish.

Comment: Going to see Fractal. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) are good for this.

Let's assume your data is stored in a model called Customer. I would write an accessor like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{

    protected $appends = ['photo_file']; // In order to see the new attribute in json dumps

    public function getPhotoPathAttribute()
    {
        $name = $this->getAttribute('photo_file');

        if(!isset($name))
            return null;

        return '/full/path/to/image/' . $name;
    }
}
```

This way you can now call `$customer->photo_path` and it will return `/full/path/to/image/image_name.jpg' (or null if the attribute is not set).

**Edit:**

In order to show this attribute in jsons (without specifically calling `$model->photo_path`) you will also need to add `protected $appends = ['photo_file']` to the model (updated).

I would recommend against overriding original name (so I leave photo_file attribute untouched).

Comment: Hi @devk. Appends works for me, yes. But I wouldn't like to put these properties everytime I retrieve informations about a Customer. Turns out that the best option for me was creating a function to retrieve the data specifically to the API, and then changed the properties using `each` function. But I used your tip to add an extra information to all the Customers with `appends` property. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are building Laravel API, sure, as [Matthew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43019968/2850062) said, go and check [Fractal](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/). But don't forget to [Dingo](https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki), the best tool for building API at Laravel. And it uses Fractal too.

Comment: DIdn't know about Dingo. Going to see it. Thanks :)